# Using jQuery in overridden new tab, in Chrome Extension, violates Content Security Policy?

Tags: jquery, google-chrome-extension

I have a chrome extension, where I override the newtab with an html file 'index.html'.
 I want to use [`jQuery`](https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js) on this *'index.html'*.

How can I do this ?

Here's my simplified code:

*manifest.json*

```
{
    "name": "Test Name",
    "description": "Test Description",
    "version": "0.1",
    "chrome_url_overrides": {
        "newtab": "index.html"
    },
    "manifest_version": 2,
}
```

*index.html*

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="index.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div> Hello World ! </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

*index.js*

```
console.log('Extension loaded successfully ...');
console.log($('div')); // console.log(jQuery('div'));
```

But I keep getting the following two errors in console.

> Refused to load the script
>   'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'
>   because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive:
>   "script-src 'self' chrome-extension-resource:".
>
> Extension loaded successfully ...
>
> Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined

**UPDATE: 1** I also tried to add [content security policy](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy) in manifest file, but it doesn't work, and still generating the error:

```
"content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js 'unsafe-eval'; object-src 'self'",
```

**UPDATE: 2** I also tried to add permissions in manifest file, but it doesn't work too, still same errors:

```
"permissions": [ "http://*/", "https://*/" ]
```

How can I solve this ?

Comment: Try a local file version of jQuery

Comment: In case of local file, the two errors disappear, but the $('div') selector returns empty array.

Comment: You'll have to provide permissions, checkout permissions and content security policy in manifest docs

Comment: @Mr.Alien I added the following line in manifest.json, but it didn't work too "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js 'unsafe-eval'; object-src 'self'",

Comment: @AshrafBashir what about permissions parameter?

Comment: @Mr.Alien: tried "permissions": [ "http://*/", "https://*/" ] but it causes the same errors

Comment: Yep, it returned an empty array just because the code is executed before the div element is rendered.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're using a wrong format for the CSP string. The correct one would be (note the absence of path):

```
"content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' https://ajax.googleapis.com 'unsafe-eval'; object-src 'self'"
```

However, it's a better practice to include a local copy of libraries you use in Chrome extensions, and not rely on a CDN.

Imagine your new tab page completely failing to load properly because the connection is not working, or loading slowly because of a poor connection.

Answer (score 1):

Try using a local file and use `$( document ).ready()` to run your `console.log`, the array may be returning empty because the DOM is not ready:

```javascript
$(document).ready(function(){
    console.log($('div'));
})
```

Comment: This work for local hosted jQuery file. not for external hosted, i.e. https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js

Comment: @AshrafBashir That's the difference between `ready` and `load` events ;)